# How to re-run the file permission check during installation?

Tags: magento-1.9, file-permissions

I accidentally screwed up the folder permissions of the Magento root directory.

Is it possible to re-run the folder permissions check during installation to have Magento ***verify*** that everything is working normally, as opposed to me manually checking the folders?

Note: I am not asking how to set the permissions. I am asking how to have Magento verify they are correct for me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using this method:

1. Rename `app/etc/local.xml` to `app/etc/local.xml.bak`
2. Empty Magento cache by removing everything under var
3. The installation wizard will now be shown.
4. If it gets to the database configuration page, the file system checks were passed.
5. Rename `local.xml` back.
6. Empty the cache again.

That should put the site back to is original status.

Comment: This is extremely bad advise. This will not check or reset the file permissions. The only thing it will do it alert you if the permissions are too restrictive, it will not tell you about permissions which are too loose. Pretty much every other answer on this page is better.

Answer (score 17):

Use The following commands to set permissions, it may help

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;     
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;     
find ./media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;   
chmod 777 ./app/etc              
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not what the question is asking. I'm not asking how to set the permissions, but how to have Magento *verify* them.

Comment: are you facing any specific issue ?

Comment: Not at this moment, but I'd like a definitive Magento test saying "everything is tested and ok" rather than "I clicked around randomly and things *appears* to be normal".

Comment: This is the best approach.

Answer (score 7):

> I accidentally screwed up the folder permissions of the Magento root directory.

There is no harm in resetting the correct permissions. For more information on permissions you can consult the official website: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

You can use an FTP or SSH program to visually see what the file permissions are for the files and directories.

> Note: I am not asking how to set the permissions. I am asking how to have Magento verify they are correct for me.

This doesn't exist, the purpose of this check during installation script is to ensure that certain directories have the right permissions so they can be written to otherwise Magento wouldn't load properly.

The correct method to address your situation is to simply reset the permissions.